# Colocar como checked um checkbox recuperado do LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, checkbox, localstorage

Galera tenho uma tabela que cada produto tem os adicionais iguais e são escolhidos a partir de um checkbox.
Depois eu checo com essa função quando da refresh quais foram escolhidos e coloco `checked` mas pelo fato de terem adicionais com id igual então ta botando o checkbox do produto debaixo também em `checked`.

```
function Adicionais() {
        var adicionais = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Adicionais"));
        for (var x in adicionais) {
            $(".Adicionais .AdicionalEscolhido[value=" + adicionais[x].idAdicional + "]").parent().find(".quantidadeAdicional").val(adicionais[x].quantidade);
            // $(".Adicionais .AdicionalEscolhido[value=" + adicionais[x].idAdicional + "]").prop("checked", "true");
            if ($(".Adicionais .AdicionalEscolhido[value=" + adicionais[x].idAdicional + "]")) {
                $(".Adicionais .AdicionalEscolhido[value=" + adicionais[x].idAdicional + "]").hide();
                $(".Adicionais .AdicionalEscolhido[value=" + adicionais[x].idAdicional + "]").closest("div").find('button[class=close]').show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seu problema está bem complicado de entender, tente explicar um pouco mais dá sua dúvida. Seja bem Vindo ao StackOverflow, é interessante dá uma lida no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre o site.

Comment: Marconi ja consegui resolver o meu problema eu fiz um dos elementos que eu tinha com id diferente na td de cada produto procurar um checkbox com id igual ao valor referente ao checkbox armazenado no meu localStorage ai agora so marco o checkbox que realmente estiver vinculado ao produto daquela TD e não colocando todos como checked igual fazia antes com a função acima fiz dessa forma  ` var checkbox = $(".Adicionais .produtoEscolhido[value=" + adicionais[x].idProduto + "]").parent().find("input.AdicionalEscolhido[value="+adicionais[x].idAdicional+"]").pro("checked","true");`